# Silverlight Vertical Slide Panel

Tags: controls, silverlight-2.0

Can anyone recommend a good Silverlight 2.0 slide panel that takes an unknown number of user controls as children and allows the user to scroll up and down through the child list.

Similar to http://www.thejamesbondmovies.com/ but vertical and not just limited to images.

Answer (score 0):

Looking around [Rob](http://www.robertjantuit.nl/index.php/2008/09/13/storyboard-animation-for-the-scrollviewer-animationhelpercontrol/) has a good starting point. His example uses adapts the ScrollViewer control, hides the default scroll bars and adds buttons to scroll left and right. He also adds a story board to animate the ScrollToHorizontalOffset. This can be easily adapted to use vertical orientation.

Anyone else seen other implementations that work vertically and has has had the default styles updates to create a experience similar to the James bond movie link above?